# I have to get several categories names selected by user in NotesUiView. Is it possible?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, hcl

I want user to select several categories in categorized view by mouse left-click, so I can write a script to print documents that belongs to different categories without selecting every document.
I have to get selected categories names by lotusscript. Is it possible?

I can get one category name:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUiWorkspace
Dim uiView as NotesUiView
Set uiView = ws.CurrentView
Dim category As String
Set category = uiView.CaretCategory
```

But how can I get several categories names, if user selects more than one category?

[screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6jIF.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: you can‘t...

unfortunately there is no way at all to get selected categories, neither by LotusScript not by any other means..

the most you can get is a NoteId... but although it increases when selecting categories further down the view there is no way to map this random id to a real category. I tried for weeks and weeks and used any trick I can think of (and there are a lot of them, as I work with Notes / Domino since 25 years now), but I could not find any workaround.

Sorry to say: you are stuck with this approach... you could show a dialog form with a @DbColumn() on the categorized column and let the user select from a DialogList item or whatever pleases you. But selecting / identifying more than one category in a view is not possible (unless you select the documents belonging to the categories and read the values from them).

Comment: It is actually possible to map a NoteId to a category using the C API (it requires reading multiple entries and searching for a match), but that still doesn't do what the asker wants because it's only single-selection.

Comment: Thanks o lot! To create a menu from categories - is a very good idea! I think it will be almost a thing that customer needs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible in the Notes client, though you could do it with a custom web interface.

There are no officially documented APIs to get all selected categories in Notes.

`NotesUIView.CaretCategory`, which you have in your code, only gets the category for the selection rectangle, so it only works for a single selection.